# MySQL: Using aggregate function conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table named Apartments:

| id | city | addresss | price | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ajekun | 3234 cunnington court | 600 | rented |
| 2 | labadiu | 34 plantagenet house | 1000 | not rented |
| 3 | cajeun | 3 queens court | 800 | not rented |
| 4 | kaun | 23 courtlin | 500 | rented |
| 5 | dajekun | 7 simbiatu | 700 | not rented |
| 6 | jekuni | 3 freshmark court | 900 | not rented |

I want to write a query to output the apartments whose prices are greater than the average and are also not rented, sorted by the 'Price' column.

Below was my query but it was wrong...
`SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE price > AVG(price) AND status = "not rented" ORDER BY price`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the average:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM apartments a
WHERE a.price > (SELECT AVG(a2.price) FROM apartments a2) AND
      a.status = 'not rented'
ORDER BY a.price
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, I have tried this too but came up with nothing

Comment: But your answer did help too, I too out a2.status = 'not rented' and I got what I wanted

Answer (score -2):

[enter link description here][1][enter image description here][2]```sql
SELECT * FROM Apartments
WHERE  price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM Apartments) AND status ='Not rented'
ORDER BY price;

```
  [1]: https://www.sololearn.com/learning/eom-project/1060/1057
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqSX0.png
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.